# Proof of normal space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ a $T_1$ space. Suppose that, for all $F$ closed in $X$ and each $W \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $F \subset W$ exists a sequence of open sets $\{W_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $F \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W_n$ and $\overline{W_n} \subset W$. Prove that $X$ is normal.

**My idea**. Let $A,B \subset X$ closed sets and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $B \subset X-A$ so $X-A$ is open then exists a sequence of open sets $\{W_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $B \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} W_n$ and $\overline{W_n} \subset X-A$

Comment: Good start. Now apply the same argument to $\overline{W_n}$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1):

SKETCH: You need to apply the hypothesis to both of the sets $A$ and $B$: there are open sets $V_n$ and $W_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n$, $B\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}W_n$, and $\operatorname{cl}V_n\subseteq X\setminus B$ and $\operatorname{cl}W_n\subseteq X\setminus A$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Now let $G_0=V_0$ and $H_0=W_0\setminus\operatorname{cl}G_0$. If open sets $G_k$ and $H_k$ have been defined for $k=0,\ldots,n$, let

$$G_{n+1}=V_{n+1}\setminus\operatorname{cl}\bigcup_{k=0}^nH_k$$

and

$$H_{n+1}=W_{n+1}\setminus\operatorname{cl}\bigcup_{k=0}^{n+1}H_k\,.$$

Now let $G=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n$ and $H=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}H_n$, and show that $G$ and $H$ are disjoint open nbhds of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

If you’ve seen a proof that $T_3$ Lindelöf spaces are normal, this should look quite familiar.